# Convert string to javascript array calling AJAX php curl call

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

How do I convert this result to a javascript array?

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 Oct 2021 09:19:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 796
Connection: keep-alive

{
"refresh_token_expires_in" : "7779999",
"refresh_token_status" : "approved",
"api_product_list" : "[trustpilot-client-api, public_data]",
"app_enduser" : "APIID",
"api_product_list_json" : [ "trustpilot-client-api", "public_data" ],
"organization_name" : "trustpilot",
"developer.email" : "dev.accounts+developerapps@trustpilot.com",
"token_type" : "BearerToken",
"issued_at" : "1633166368319",
"client_id" : "CLIENTID",
"access_token" : "ACCESSTOKEN",
"refresh_token" : "TOKENNAME",
"application_name" : "NAME6",
"scope" : "",
"refresh_token_issued_at" : "1633166368319",
"expires_in" : "359999",
"refresh_count" : "0",
"status" : "approved"
}

I thought it would be as simple as the PHP encoding it, then the Javascript using JSON.parse but I then get the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0**

PHP Code:

```
$payload = http_build_query(array(
'grant_type' => 'password',
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password
));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken'); //Url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' .  base64_encode($apiKey . ':' . $secretKey),
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

$content=curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo json_encode($error_msg);
} else {
    
    echo json_encode($content);

}
curl_close($ch);
```

AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api-test-access-token.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {

            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);


        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` above to `false` (or remove the line) as it will add the headers to the output of `curl_exec` and of course this is not a valid JSON. `$content` will then just contain the body of the response.

From the PHP documentation (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
CURLOPT_HEADER  |  true to include the header in the output.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's worked perfectly. You won't believe how long I've been trying different things with this - much appreciated!! StackOverflow should have the option so I can buy you a beer!!

Comment: Great to hear! Please mark this answer as `accepted` to help others to find the solution quicker.

Comment: All done mate, had to wait 3 minutes to trigger it.